# spring + hibernate sharing properties and annotations

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-roo

Newbie question.

I have some Spring/Hibernate entity beans defined like this:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooJpaEntity
public class MyEntity {     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="uuid-char")
    private String id;

    ...
}
```

I want that ALL my entities have an Id field defined exactly like the one above. 
What's the best way to share properties between entity beans ? (I prefer not to extend a common abstract class and possibily without falling back to aop).

Is there some Hibernate "entity template" to tweak ? Can I do it through annotations only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way in Hibernate and core Java except inherit the class from a common super class (`@MappedSuperclass`).

The Reason why it is impossible is that you need a class with that field (java) therefore hibernate can not modify the standard java behavior.

But with help of AspectJ you can. A bit like Spring-Roo add the `id` value you can do it in own AspectJ Advice.

I have in mind some AspectJ Intertype declaration that add the `@Id...private Spring id` field to every class that has an `@Entity` annotation.

---

On the other hand, I have the feeling that this is overengineered. I personly use a template in my IDE, so I do not have to write all the stuff. And this is fine for me.

Comment: thank you. about "I have in mind some AspectJ Intertype declaration that add the Id...private Spring id field to every class that has an Entity annotation." do you have any code sample ?